# How to write this sql to make it to be understood easily

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  BusLine.LineCode AS RouteID,
  BusStation.Station AS StartStation, BusStation_1.Station AS EndStation,
  BusStation_1.StationIndex - BusStation.StationIndex AS StopCount
FROM  BusLine AS BusLine_1 
    INNER JOIN Area AS Area_1 
        ON BusLine_1.AreaID = Area_1.ID 
    INNER JOIN BusInfo AS BusInfo_1 
        ON BusLine_1.ID = BusInfo_1.BusLineID 
    INNER JOIN BusStation AS BusStation_1 
        ON BusInfo_1.ID = BusStation_1.BusInfoID 
    INNER JOIN 
        Area 
        INNER JOIN BusLine 
            ON Area.ID = BusLine.AreaID 
        INNER JOIN BusInfo 
            ON BusLine.ID = BusInfo.BusLineID 
        INNER JOIN BusStation 
            ON BusInfo.ID = BusStation.BusInfoID
        ON BusStation_1.StationIndex > BusStation.StationIndex AND   BusInfo_1.ID = BusInfo.ID
WHERE  (Area.City = 'NewYork')
```

I have read the above sql for ten minutes, however I can not understand it because of this line:

```
    INNER JOIN 
        Area 
        INNER JOIN BusLine
```

I wonder if anyone can explain it and  re-factor it to make it easily understood ?

---

update schema:

Area:

```
ID
Name
```

BusLine:

```
ID
AreaID --> ID in Area
LineCode
```

BusInfo:

```
ID
BusLineID --> ID in BusLine
```

BusStation:

```
BusInfoID --> ID in BusInfo
```

BTW, I am using the Access, it seems that I have to use the `( )` to wrap the `innjer join`.

Comment: you have to give your schema also then only any one could explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original author has been considerate enough to indent the SQL in a way that indicates how the joins are logically related.

It can be rewritten as:

```
FROM  BusLine AS BusLine_1 
    INNER JOIN Area AS Area_1 
        ON BusLine_1.AreaID = Area_1.ID 
    INNER JOIN BusInfo AS BusInfo_1 
        ON BusLine_1.ID = BusInfo_1.BusLineID 
    INNER JOIN BusStation AS BusStation_1 
        ON BusInfo_1.ID = BusStation_1.BusInfoID 
    INNER JOIN BusStation 
        ON BusStation_1.StationIndex > BusStation.StationIndex
    INNER JOIN BusInfo 
        ON BusInfo.ID = BusStation.BusInfoID AND BusInfo_1.ID = BusInfo.ID
    INNER JOIN BusLine 
        ON BusLine.ID = BusInfo.BusLineID 
    INNER JOIN Area 
        ON Area.ID = BusLine.AreaID 
WHERE  (Area.City = 'NewYork')
```

EDIT: I should add, the nested inner join syntax is simply a way to indicate precedence, i.e. this set of joins should be (logically) performed before the others. Some SQL engines support the use of parentheses for this purpose. Where all the joins are inner joins there is no logical difference between the nested and non-nested forms (i.e. the SQL you provided and the alternative SQL I provided above).

Comment: Your codes can run, can you tell me the difference between the two of them?

Comment: There is no logical difference between the two or at least there shouldn't be.

Comment: Then in my original post, can you tell me the join order?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that's confusing you isn't exactly the section you've highlighted. `INNER JOIN Area` is joining first with the part above, because the following part `INNER JOIN BusLine ON Area.ID = BusLine.AreaID` is a regular, standard join with a clause.

IF (and that's a big if) I've read this query correctly (the bus lines leaving New York with the number of stops they have), here's what I'd try to refactor it

```
SELECT  BusLine.LineCode AS RouteID,
  BusStation.Station AS StartStation, BusStation_1.Station AS EndStation,
  BusStation_1.StationIndex - BusStation.StationIndex AS StopCount
FROM  BusLine AS BusLine_1 
    INNER JOIN Area AS Area_1 
        ON BusLine_1.AreaID = Area_1.ID 
    INNER JOIN BusInfo AS BusInfo_1 
        ON BusLine_1.ID = BusInfo_1.BusLineID 
    INNER JOIN BusStation AS BusStation_1 
        ON BusInfo_1.ID = BusStation_1.BusInfoID 
    INNER JOIN Area 
        ON BusStation_1.StationIndex > BusStation.StationIndex AND   BusInfo_1.ID = BusInfo.ID AND Area.City = 'NewYork'
    INNER JOIN BusLine 
        ON Area.ID = BusLine.AreaID 
    INNER JOIN BusInfo 
        ON BusLine.ID = BusInfo.BusLineID 
    INNER JOIN BusStation 
        ON BusInfo.ID = BusStation.BusInfoID
```

Please tell me if the result set is the same!

Comment: I add the `(` to the sql to run it in the access, but it tell me there are syntax errors:http://pastebin.com/UqQ0YBHJ

Comment: Syntax error where? also, in your pastebin'd query there are parenthesis which i didn't write. Maybe they're mismatched?

Comment: I add the parenthesis, because I am using Access, it seems that the parenthesis are required.

Comment: this solution was tailored assuming mysql. I guess that you added parenthesis in the wrong places, i'm sorry.